# avoid embedding truetype font

Tags: fonts, xdvipdfmx

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\begin{document}
שלום
\end{document}
```

the specified font can be found in the culmus package (http://culmus.sourceforge.net/download.html).

compiling with xelatex . everything is fine, and I can see the document as it should be.

now, the font is embedded inside the document.
this is fine most of the time, but the mentioned font is licensed under GPL, without font exception. this renders my whole document GPL, which contradicts the license of the contents.

how can I create a document that will not embed the font?

NOTE: I don't want to use bitmap fonts, and not to "scan" the document into some raster format. I just want that the document will rely on the given font to be provided by the viewer system, instead of providing it embedded.

Comment: Where exactly is that stated? From the license I can only see who has the copyright on the Frank font. The fonts that are under GPL explicitly states that unaltered embedding in documents are ok.

Comment: looking at the LICENSE file in the, e.g., OpenBSD package, you can see that some fonts are GPL with FE, while FrankRuehl (and others as well) are simply GPL.
embedding in the document is ok, of course, but the lack of the exception means the document itself becomes GPL.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_font_exception